# django multilingual site and subdomain

Tags: django, subdomain, multilingual

Is there a way to create a multilingual site with django and subdomains ?

I would like to have this :

en.mysite.com -> site in english
it.mysite.com -> site in italian

I have heard of localeurl app but it's mainly for the url path like /en/index.html or /it/index.html.

Comment: Have a look at this article http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2008/12/12/handling-subdomains-in-django/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [domain framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls) to get current domain:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
language = domain.split('.')[0]
```

Or take it from [HTTP_HOST META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META):

```
domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
language = domain.split('.')[0]
```

Then [activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate) language:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate(language)
```

You can write your own middleware with this code.